# Storing Values in 2 Dimensional Array C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am attempting to solve this problem where I find the least amount of coins necessary in order to dispense change from my current float. I have implemented the logic, and it is currently working accordingly, however I am required to store the coin value and the quantity necessary in order to dispense the change. I was thinking to store it within a 2 dimensional array, although I cannot get it to work. So far this is my implemented logic:

```
// Reverse Sort Array
        Array.Reverse(quantities); // quantities for each coin
        Array.Reverse(coins); // coins start from $2 -> 0.05cents

        int counter = 0;
        int coin;
        for (int i = 0; i < coins.Length; i++)
        {
            coin = Math.Min(quantities[i], (int)(change / coins[i]));
            counter += coin;
            change -= coin * coins[i];
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Number of coins = {0}", counter); // total coins
    }
```

Can anyone provide any advice on how this can be done? I am not allowed to use anything in the Collection classes, and believe me I would if I could. All answers are appreciated.
Cheers.

Comment: why do you tag with c and java?

Comment: If your not allowed to use dynamic lists then this sounds like an exercise in expanding a fixed size array, therefore your 2d array idea is correct and each iteration you need to create a new 2d array that encompases the previous 2d array values along with the new value

Comment: Consider using `Decimal` type for the coin values.

Answer (score 0):

why not use a single array and a custom class?
In the real world you would probably choose a dictionary (or a sorted dictionary),
but it looks like an exercise like Sayse wrote.
You can create a simple class that contains the quantity, value per coin, and total value of coins, and use this class for your calculations.